# Load open layers map to electron js with typescript imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm trying to load openlayers map in electron using typescript imports. But when compiling following exception pops up

### [image]

This is the code I am trying to run

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Is there a way to load latest open layers with electron?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go with an OSM source?

```
  import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  import View from 'ol/View.js';
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

  var map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```